# Prevent element from taking part in text selection

Tags: html, css, textselection

I have some source code in a `<pre><code>` with line numbers in a separate `<div>`. When the text is selected, the line numbers come with it, and are subsequently copied. Is there any way to prevent the line numbers from being a part of the selection, even if I select the elements above and below the source code block?

I'd like to avoid JavaScript for the benefit of people who browse with it off. (With JavaScript, I'd add a button to hide the line numbers).

`unselectable="on"` and the various vendor-specific `user-select` CSS properties did not work; the numbers are still selected and copied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the element you want to prevent selection of an id.

Then put this in your CSS:

```
#id-name {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
::-moz-selection {
   background: transparent;
}
::selection { 
   background: transparent; 
}
```

Comment: Aaaah. I understand now. The element still appears to be selected (I'm using Firefox), but the text is not actually selected and nothing is copied. To disable the selection appearance I added `::-moz-selection { background: transparent; }` and `::selection { background: transparent; }` on the element.

Comment: Could you add the `::selection` bits to your answer? (if you don't mind)