# Disable text selection on input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Hybrid application using IBM Worklight, HTML5, CSS3 and javascript.
Is there any possible way to disable text selection on input fields?

I have a username and password field on the screen and want to disable the user from selecting text within the input fields. Also, copy paste should be disabled.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is? The usual ways of preventing text selection doesn't really work inside elements where text selection is considered a crucial part of the functionality.

Comment: `element.onmousedown = function(){ return false; };` maybe? (Obviously other events need to specifically handled also, if so.)

Comment: Can you confirm that you still want the user to still be able to edit the contents of the input boxes?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to disable copy and paste

```
$('input,textarea').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable pasting text into input field,

```
$('#myInput').bind('input', function(e) {
    $("#myInput").val("");    //This will reset input value to empty
});
```

Answer (score -2):

There is an answer already on SO for selecting that will probably give you what you need:
[Prevent element from taking part in text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151908/prevent-element-from-taking-part-in-text-selection)

There are also answers on SO for disabling pasting on some browsers:
[Disable pasting text into HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript)

Keep in mind though that the above will not work in every browser.