# How to stop selection by mouse in an input type without making it disable/readonly

Tags: javascript, html

There is html-code:

```
<input type="text">
```

I need to deny selecting text in `<input>`

Comment: `<input type="text" disabled>`

Comment: Do you want to it to be edited but not to selected?

Comment: Yes. Only edit, don't selected.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: See question that was answered already on SO.  [Disable text selection on input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773049/disable-text-selection-on-input-fields)

Comment: decision:<br/>for mozilla: use css:<br/>input { -moz-user-select: none; }<br/>for other: use js<br/>$('input').bind('mousemove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });

Answer (score 2):

Since `user-select: none` won't work for an input, you could solve it like this:

```css
.invisable-selection::selection { 
  background: transparent; 
}
```

```html
<input class="invisable-selection" type="text" value="test" oncopy="return false">
```

It won't show the selection and it won't copy the value.

Comment: but easily  modify this using inspect element

Comment: @MostafaBaezid yeah obviously. You cannot prevent this.

Answer (score -2):

You may try like, it's not affect any major style changes,

```html
<input type="text" value="john" readonly>
```

Comment: Using your live test case, I **can** select the text with the mouse and I **can't** edit it, so it fails the requirements in the question on at least two counts.