# Prevent select on input text field

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to prevent selection on an input field with the following considerations

- Prevent selection using mouse
- Prevent selection using keyboard (including Ctrl+A, shift+arrows)
- Allow focusing into field using keyboard and mouse

So far I have tried these things:

**CSS**

I have attempted the using the following class

```
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Result: selection still possible

I have also tried below with no success:

```
$("#my_field").attr('unselectable','on')
     .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
           '-moz-user-select':'none',
           '-o-user-select':'none',
           '-khtml-user-select':'none', 
           '-webkit-user-select':'none',
           '-ms-user-select':'none',
           'user-select':'none'
     }).bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; });
```

**Javascript**

I tried the below

```
$( "#my_field" ).select(function(e) {
        console.log("Select called");
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Result: console printed the message, however the select still works

Thanks for your help

Comment: not really, those solutions don't apply to inputs

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151908/prevent-element-from-taking-part-in-text-selection

Comment: @Joel that solution makes it look like its not being selected, however the selection still happens and I can drag that selection to another field

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It can be done by setting the element's `selectionStart` to `selectionEnd` on [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) event:

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('my_input');

inp.addEventListener('select', function() {
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd;
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="my_input" type="text" value="Try to select me!" />
```

Comment: *Prevent selection using keyboard* —the above doesn't meet this criterion. Use tab to focus the field, which selects the entire content by default, so the value can then be copied. I don't know why anyone would want to do this anyway.

Comment: @RobG That's right, however we can do the same thing on `focus` event — http://jsbin.com/remihecomi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: @HashemQolami—it's still possible to select the content by starting the selection from outside the element. And in any reasonably modern browser I can inspect the element and copy the content from the inspector. Really, this sort of stuff is pointless.

Comment: @HashemQolami Selection is also possible, when starting selection from inside the input and stopping outside.

Comment: @OlivierKrull I couldn't reproduce it. Can you provide an online example?

Comment: @HashemQolami Well I just used your example above. I try to solve the same problem right now and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution (maybe css only) meanwhile?

Comment: @OlivierKrull Well, I cannot see the effect on Chrome/Ubuntu 16. However as RobG pointed out, this sort of things might be pointless as there will be always a way to get the content of an input and I just tried to give an answer to the OP's question at the time :)

Comment: @HashemQolami of course I fully understand :-). I'm on Chrome => macOs High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 6):

You can prevent the `mousedown` event to prevent the selection of the text inside the `input`.

```html
<input type="text" id="unselectable" value="You can not select this text!"/>
<script>
document.getElementById("unselectable").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This prevents the input to be focused by mouse click.

Answer (score 6):

You can cover over the `<input>` with any layer in absolute position, for example with `div.wrapper::after` or with other wrapper tag. Then use `user-select: none` for the wrapper tag (`<div>`, `<label>`, etc) and don't use `user-select: none` on the `<input>` itself.

But if your wrapper tag is `<label>` I recommend additionally adding the attribute `readonly` for the `<input>` and converting `<label>` to the block (or inline-block / flex / inline-flex).

```css
input { outline: none; margin: 10px 0; width: 200px; }

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

label.wrapper { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="Any text in the div wrapper"/>
</div>

<label class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="Any text in the label wrapper" readonly />
</label>
```

Comment: :D Thanks for the answer, I asked this more than 4 years ago. Hopefully, helps someone else

Comment: And even then: it sadly allows for selection using the keyboard (tab to highlight the input box, auto-selected on focus)

Answer (score 5):

### CSS-only solution:

This will not allow for input text to ***visually*** appear selected, while it is.
There are situations where this technique is good enough, if the developer do not care for the input's text to be able to be copy-pasted, but only the *visual* aspect of the selection is unwanted.

```css
input{ color:transparent }
input::selection{ color:transparent }
```

```html
<input value='invisible selection'>
```

It's also possible to use `font-size:0` if `width` & `height` are defined on the `input` element.

### JS Solution:

When the input gets focused → unfocus it (by calling the `blur` method):

```html
<input value='unselectable selection' onfocus='this.blur()'>
```

Comment: input::selection {background-color: transparent}
gives the perfect result

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for when if you want pointer icon with cursor.

```css
.input-select {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-select::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-select">
  <input type="text" value="any"/>
</div>
```