# How to prevent highlighting of text upon selecting text in input field

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to copy text in the input field but without highlighting selected text. Below is the code snippet,

```
click = () => {
    this.input_ref.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
};

<input readOnly ref={this.input_ref} value="hello"/>
<button onClick={this.click}>COPY</button>
```

I have tried add css to input field as below but did not work.

```
.no_select {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
outline: none;
}
<input classname="no_select" readOnly ref={this.input_ref} value="hello"/>
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222158/4321808 or  simply make the input a div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent select on input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221991/prevent-select-on-input-text-field)

Comment: It still highlights the text in input field

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to my question and thought would help others too. So posting an answer here.
On clicking copy button after copying the text to clipboard i used
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges() to deselect the text in input field. Below is the code snippet,

```
click = () => {
   this.input_ref.current.select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
};
```

**EDITED:** Above above only for chrome and not on IE11 so used the below lines which works both on chrome and IE11 to deselect text in input field.

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.getSelection().addRange(document.createRange());
```