# How to make text not visible in a text box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I want to use a textbox on WordPress as password, I don't want the text to display after inputting on the textbox. Is there any CSS code I can use to achieve this?

Below code is what I have but the text on the textbox is still visible. Kindly help look into this if there is any mistakes I'm making.

```
  <table border="0" style="background:#ececec" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="left"><td>Email address</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr align="left"><td>Password</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="email"></td></tr>
    <INPUT type="text" STYLE="color: #FFFFFF;
    <tr align="left"><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'><font face="arial" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.everythingeloma.com">Everythingeloma.com</a> by Netbuilder Ltd.</font></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you not simply use the `<input type="password">` ?

Comment: -webkit-text-security: disc;
hope so that will help you .

Answer (score 0):

Simply use password box input box instead of text box. If you are using default text box provided by WordPress or certain plugins then you need to put code for making it look like password.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Comment: I try the code but it doesn't work, the text are still visible. I actually don't want to use the password box.

Comment: then use css property -webkit-text-security: disc;

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use

```
<input type="password" />
```

or

use css property **-webkit-text-security**

webkit only solution

```css
.password-field{
   -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input class="password-field" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set colour as a textbox background colour.

```css
.nonvisible
 {
   color:white;
 }
```

```html
<input type="password" class="nonvisible">
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable your text box in html mood and put

```
<p class="my-text">

 write your text here

</p> 

and go to the customization and add custom css

<style>
.my-text{
color:white;
}
</style>

OR

<style>
.my-text{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this can be :

```
input,
input::selection {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

To the previous answers using color, i added the pseudo element `::selection` to avoid showing the password on a simple selection and opacity 0 to the text (which might be a bit redondant).


But this way you can still 'copy paste' the password so you might want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221991/prevent-select-on-input-text-field?lq=1), or use something like that as attribut to your input :

```
oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"
ondrop="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"
```

That being said the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to use `type='password'` on your `input` and an `rgba` color with 0 for the 4th value if you don't want to see the little stars. Adding a selector with `::selection` to your `input` will hide them also when selected.