# How to remove selection highlighting for input field in JavaScript for Vive Focus Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, input, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I'm trying to disable selection highlighting and the context menu (Copy, Cut, Select All, etc.) of input fields using JavaScript on a Vive Focus VR headset Android WebView.

I've tried the below solutions, but none of them work for the Vive Focus:

Solution #1:

```
$.fn.extend({
    disableSelection : function() {
        this.each(function() {
            this.onselectstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
            this.unselectable = "on";
            $(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none');
            $(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none');
        });
    }
});

$(function() {
    $(this).disableSelection();
});
```

Solution #2:

```
function disableSelect(el){         
    if(el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener("mousedown",disabler,"false");
    } else {
        el.attachEvent("onselectstart",disabler);
    }
}

function enableSelect(el){
    if(el.addEventListener){
    el.removeEventListener("mousedown",disabler,"false");
    } else {
        el.detachEvent("onselectstart",disabler);
    }
}

function disabler(e){
    if(e.preventDefault){ e.preventDefault(); }
    return false;
}
```

Solution #3:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {return false;};
```

Solution #4:

```
function absorbEvent_(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
    node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
    node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
    node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
    node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
}

function init() {
    preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('theimage'));
}
```

I posted another question ([How to remove selection highlighting for input field in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866769/how-to-remove-selection-highlighting-for-input-field-in-css)) related to this about using CSS to achieve this, but unfortunately, it does not disable the selection/context menu on the Vive Focus for input fields.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks